# How to use (shell) find to recursively find files of specific type then cp only the newest one for each folder

Tags: shell

I'm trying to write a script that goes into a folder that has a bunch of zip files that were unzipped, then use the find command to search each subdirectory recursively, look for files of the .MCA type, and finally copy only the newest one to another directory. So far I can't figure out how to grab only the newest file. Would -newer work? How would I do this for every file?

```
find . -mindepth 2 -name "*.MCA" -exec cp {} tempMCA \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `rsync` instead of `cp` then you can run:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -name '*.MCA' -exec rsync --update {} tmpMCA \;
```

The `--update` option tells `rsync` to only copy the files if the source is newer than the destination.

Comment: I used this command but it doesn't do anything. I should mention that in each subfolder there usually around 3-15 of these .MCA files and I only want the newest one. Their title has a timestamp I could use to compare as well.